# Avoid repeated code in Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5.3, google-ads-api

In each controller in my Laravel application, I use all of this namespace:

```
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Google\Auth\OAuth2;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\CampaignService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\OrderBy;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\Paging;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\Selector;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\SortOrder;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
```

I need a way to avoid repeating all this code in my controller. I have tried to put it in a base controller and then extend all other controller from this but it did't work.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using PHP 7, you can group these.

Example

```
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\CampaignService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\OrderBy;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\Paging;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\Selector;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\SortOrder;
```

Becomes

```
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\{CampaignService, OrderBy, Paging, Selector, SortOrder};
```

You can also do something like the following which should work on older versions of PHP.

```
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords;

$adWordsServices = new AdWords\AdWordsServices;
$campaignService = new AdWords\v201609\cm\CampaignService;
```

This cuts down on what you need to import but requires you to fill in the remainder of the namespace you did not import when instantiating.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.group

Comment: just out of curiosity, what if it isn't PHP 7?

Comment: The second part of my answer should work then where you import the namespace rather than the class.

Comment: i use PHP5.6 but in the two way i must repeat the code in all my controllers if not in the beginning, in the body of the controller.  Thanks @user3158900

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a lot of logic in your controllers. You could create more specific classes that does certain logic. Ex create a class that handles all GoogleApi interactions then in your controller import that class.

`app/GoogleApi/AdWords.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\GoogleApi;

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\CampaignService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\OrderBy;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\Paging;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\Selector;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\SortOrder;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;

class AdWords
{
    public function auth() 
    {
        // auth logic
    }
    // other methods
}
```

Then in your controllers you'll only have
`use App\GoogleApi\AdWords`.

If you are using php 7 already have a good answer, if not you can do something like this:

Instead of :

```
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
...
```

put only

```
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords;
```

then in your code to use that namespace classes:

```
$service = new AdWords\AdWordsServices;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeh I make an adwords website that give me charts of all my campaigns in it to watch all of them in the same page. so each controller is different goolge adwords call. but i like your idea and i want to try it . Thanks